# how to get a travel agency bookings list in my app ( using amadeus )

Tags: integration, amadeus

I built a software for a travel agency in which they can enter their offers , keep track of their expenses etc

the travel agency i'm working with  book flights for its clients threw amadeus platform

what i want to do  is get the bookings list of the travel agency in my software  so i can calculate the expenses more efficiently

any idea on how to achieve that

i've search in the amadeus self service apis  but no api allows to get the bookings list

i tried searching in amadeus self service apis   but i havent found any api that allows me to do what i'm looking for

Comment: You should probably contact Amadeus support for something like this.